# imread not working in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the `imread` function from OpenCV2.2.

My code is very simple.

```
cv::Mat host= imread("1.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

After that, the host matrix became filled by zeros pointers, i.e. an image has not loaded.

If I use `cvLoadImage` then it all works properly.

The file exists, and I am not mixing the release and debug libraries. Why `imread` doesn't work?

Comment: @asandwhich yes there is "Why imread doesn't work?". Isn't that a question? Probably not the best way to ask for help but still a question. People instead of just being sarcastic really try to help people !! I know many of us don't describe and ask correctly but if you're not going to help please don't bother being sarcastic.

Comment: Sorry for responding to the original question. "Why imread doesn't work?" wasn't initially in the question. I pointed that out to the asker. But, hey, I guess I need to stop that.

Answer (score 26):

Reproduced with opencv 2.4.8.

If you are running in Debug, check that you are also using debug libraries, it fixed our problem. : [OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries).

Answer (score 12):

i was facing the same problem with 2.4.6 . The reason was that while selecting the library , i had selected both the debug version and the release version. When i selected only the debug version for the library everything worked fine

Answer (score 9):

I can confirm, that there are some problems with imread in OpenCV 2.2. However the problems only occurred on a Windows 32bit system. On a linux and on a mac it worked. I can't tell why it didn't work, but we had a small workaround for that.

We fixed this problem with the following macros, maybe you could try this out and use "ourImread" from then on.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define ourImread(filename, isColor) cvLoadImage(filename.c_str(), isColor)
#else
#define ourImread(filename, isColor) imread(filename, isColor)
#endif
```

Comment: Actually this bug still exists on OpenCV 2.4.2 win32.

Comment: I also faced this issue with OpenCV 2.4.7, win32. Running with Visual Studio 2012 triggered the bug. Running in release mode on console worked sometimes.

Comment: Mixing release and debug modes is the cause of the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem

```
cv::Mat image= cv::imread("immagine12.jpg");   // Read the file

if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    return -1;
}

cv::namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image );  

//non so perchè ma senza il waitKey e lasciando solo il system pause non carica l'immagine...
cv::waitKey(5000);


system("pause");
```

but I fixed it when I inserted the `cv::waitKey(5000);`
I don't know why but with `system pause` it can't load the image and it goes on pause after it loads the image!

Comment: Mixing release and debug modes is the cause of the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem on Linux, when reading 32 bit tiff images only.

```
Mat mat= imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
```

Problem was because OpenCV was not build with Tiff support for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Opencv4.3 Windows10 x64 Visual Studio 2019 I finally solved that problem!!!

Ok, now, when you meet the problem, you can try:

1. Check your settings, make sure you don't mix include .lib file in "Project->Properties->Linker->Input" for Release/Debug, that `opencv_xxx430d.lib`(note the `d`) is for Debug, and `opencv_xxx430.lib`(no `d`) is for Release, and the platform is `x64`.
2. And in `C/C++->General`, you need to set the `Additional include directory` that `X:/(opencv_build/install)/include` and `X:/(opencv_build/install)/include/opencv2` respectively for Release/Debug.
3. Maybe you should `#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>`.
4. Finally, the Unicode Problem, which is also my problem that, the unicode symbol in the image file path, fuck! I don't know why because my code is very normal `string path = "D:/kk.jpg`(**note that, it is `/` not `\`)** but you can try to debug your code, maybe you can find there is something like `path = "?D:/kk.jpg"`, what the fuck! So don't directly copy/paste your image path, even you've already use the absolute path, you can still meet the unicode problem, so, what you need to do is delete the line of code(`string path = "D:/kk.jpg`), and then just retype each character one by one! If you're lucky, you will see that image with imshow. Good luck.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you so much for the solution and proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that it is an OpenCV bug then, please, post your image and instructions for reproducing to the [OpenCV bugtracker](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is late but someone might found this helpful. I was facing the same problem while using `imread` using OpenCV-3.0. I tried all solutions but actually I was not adding the library `opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp`. Although `imshow` was working without it, but after I add this I was able to read the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584273/issue-with-reading-an-image-using-cvimread-function-in-opencv)
2. Please make sure your path is correct ,
3. According to the Opencv's   API  , I'd try this call:

`arrayMat[i]=imread("1.jpg" , 1 );`

The parameters for imread :

```
Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags=1)
Loads an image from a file.

Parameters: 
 filename – Name of file to be loaded.
 flags – Specifies color type of the loaded image:
   >0 the loaded image is forced to be a 3-channel color image
   =0 the loaded image is forced to be grayscale
   <0 the loaded image will be loaded as-is (note that in the current implementation the alpha channel, if any, is stripped from the output image, e.g. 4-channel RGBA image will be loaded as RGB if  ).
```

Good luck 
S

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved it. The key is whether the filename has jpg.
If the filename is `p1`, you should use something like this `imread("p1.jpg")`. But we often set the filename as `p1.jpg`, here we should use something like this  `imread("p1.jpg.jpg")`.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me, my simple solution was to use the C API and then convert to `Mat`:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("c://frame_201.bmp");
Mat mat = Mat(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reverse is also true: if you are building Release and you have Debug libraries, then imread() quietly fails (errno is 0 after imread(), but the image object is not populated).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

If you're on OS X and statically link OpenCV be sure to use libjpeg which is bundled with OpenCV, not the system's one.

I had similar problem with OpenCV 3.0, except that `cvLoadImage` was not working as well. So, this might not really answer your question, but maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the very same problem that imread didn't work and cvLoadImage did work.

I decided to create a new Visual Studio from scratch and now it works.

There is no general problem with imread in OpenCV 2.4.3 under win32.

Answer (score -2):

I know you want use "imread" & "CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE" and convert automatically.
But this other way for load one picture and convert to gray scale:

```
define CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

/* load the image */
IplImage* img  = cvLoadImage("yourPicture.bmp");  //jpg - bmp

/* retrieve properties */
int width     = img->width;
int height    = img->height;
int nchannels = img->nChannels;
int step      = img->widthStep;

IplImage* img2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->height, img->width),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

/* setup the pointer to access image data */
uchar *data = ( uchar* )img->imageData;    
uchar *data2= ( uchar* )img2->imageData;

/* convert to grayscale manually */
int i, j, r, g, b, byte;
for( i = 0 ; i < height ; i++ ) {
    for( j = 0 ; j < width ; j++ ) {
        r = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 0];
        g = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 1];
        b = data[i*step + j*nchannels + 2];

        byte = ( r + g + b ) / 3;

    int v0=0, v1=0, v2=0;

    data2[i*(img2->widthStep)+j*(img2->nChannels)+0] = byte;
data2[i*(img2->widthStep)+j*(img2->nChannels)+1] = byte;
data2[i*(img2->widthStep)+j*(img2->nChannels)+2] = byte;
}
}

cvNamedWindow("ImagenColor", 1);
cvShowImage("ImagenColor", img);

cvNamedWindow("Gray", 1);
cvShowImage("Gray", img2);
}
```