# Displaying image and converting to grayscale - OpenCV for Android, Java API

Tags: java, android, image, opencv

I'm writing an Android app in Eclipse that uses the [OpenCV4Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android) API.  How can I display a `Mat` image easily, for debugging only?  In C++, according to the OpenCV tutorials, you'd do something like:

```
namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.
```

but the Java API for Android doesn't seem to have a `namedWindow` function inside `org.opencv.highgui.Highgui`.

Also, I'd like to load the image as grayscale.  In C++, according to [imread not working in Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-in-opencv), you'd do:

```
imread("blackandwhite.jpg", 0);
```

but the Java API's `Highgui.imread()` has only the filename argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summary:

Convert image to grayscale: `Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);`

Display image: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344700/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360810/).

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample code which would display an image (must have the image in drawable folder) in imageView using OpenCV:

```
 ImageVIew imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sampleImageView);
        Mat mRgba = new MAt();
        mRgba = Utils.loadResource(MainAct.this, R.drawable.your_image,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, img);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
```

and xml must have an ImageView as below :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sampleImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Hope this helps in solving your problem..

Answer (score 2):

> but the Java API for Android doesn't seem to have a namedWindow
>   function inside org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.

Because you have to show your image on `View`. Take a look at samples from WEB.

> Also, I'd like to load the image as grayscale.

Use `cvCvtColor` with code `CV_BGR2GRAY` for such type of convertion.

Comment: I'm not using JavaCV, which is a third-party wrapper to OpenCV. Rather, I'm using OpenCV for Android, which has different syntax than C++/JavaCV.  Thanks for the tip about cvCvtColor - this led me to the solution for the grayscale conversion, which is `Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)`.  I don't know what you mean about showing the image on `View`, though.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user1397061 javacv has examples of showing image on device. Also as I already said there are many examples in WEB.

Comment: `Highgui.imwrite("/image.jpg", mat)` does the trick but doesn't actually display the image - it just saves it to a file. JavaCV uses canvas frames, which don't seem to exist anywhere else. Would you mind  posting a link to an example with OpenCV4Android?

Comment: OpenCV package contains folder `samples`.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't deal with the display of the image, here is a quick pure-java static method to read an image by filepath and then convert it (and write it) into grayscale.

```
/**
 * Get an OpenCV matrix from an image path and write the image as grayscale.
 * @param filePath The image path.
 * @return The matrix.
 */
public static Mat loadOpenCvImage(final String filePath) {
    Mat imgMat = Highgui.imread(filePath, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (imgMat == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error loading file: " + filePath);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ht: " + imgMat.height() + " Width: " + imgMat.width());
        final String outPath = filePath + "_gray.jpg";
        Log.d(TAG, outPath);
        Highgui.imwrite(outPath, imgMat);
    }
    return imgMat;
}
```