# OpenCV Android - Error on loading drawable image into Mat

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I've seen the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941251/displaying-image-and-converting-to-grayscale-opencv-for-android-java-api/12362732) regarding displaying image, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) regarding context in Android, but I'm still confused to use it in my program. Here's what my program looks like:

```
Mat drawImage;
Bitmap drawBitmap;
try {
    drawImage = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.sample, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    drawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawImage.cols(), drawImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(drawImage, drawBitmap);
    viewImage.setImageBitmap(drawBitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// sample is filename of target image
// viewImage is ImageView object in .xml
```

I run the program but these errors pop out:

```
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:(III)J
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:477)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at org.opencv.android.Utils.loadResource(Utils.java:66)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.development.sign2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-30 13:04:57.965: E/AndroidRuntime(5425):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to change the context into `MainActivity.this` but it's still error. I saw the `Mat` error one so I tried to change the declaration into `Mat drawImage = new Mat()` and `Mat drawImage = new Mat(60, 60, CvType.CV_8UC3)` but no luck whatsoever.

Am I using the context wrong? Or is there something else? Any advice will help. Thanks before.

Comment: you simply can't run any opencv code in onCreate, since the native so's are not loaded yet.

Comment: Ah that explains the `Native method`. So is it okay to put the code in `onCameraFrame()` ?