# Compose panorama doesn`t work

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use a different way for stitching images, but I got the following error...I try to change the format of the images or the size but nothing happens...any ideas?

error:

> Error: Assertion failed (imgs.size() == imgs_.size())
>   in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\stitching\src\stitcher.cpp
>   , line 128

my code:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{


 Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();
 Mat image11,image22;
 Mat pano,output_frame;
 vector<Mat> imgs,currentFrames;
// Load the images
 Mat image1= imread( argv[1] );
 Mat image2= imread( argv[2] );

 printf("-- umwandlung works");

currentFrames.push_back(image1);
currentFrames.push_back(image2);

stitcher.estimateTransform( currentFrames );

stitcher.composePanorama(currentFrames, output_frame );



 waitKey(0);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you have so many unused variables? BTW, check if your `imread`s are actually successful. It could be, for example, that you are trying to load some jpg images without jpg support enabled in OpenCV. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12854400/2436175) you find an example on how to check if the image has been loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because estimateTransform() is not able to stitch all the images you have provided. You can check how many images were stitched using Stitcher::component(), it returns a vector of ints, which size is your goal.
Therefore, in your case its size should be 2 if the stitching was successful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is similiar to this one:

[using compose panorama without estimateTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874550/using-compose-panorama-without-estimatetransform)

I've just answered you there.