# using compose panorama without estimateTransform

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use compose panorama without estimateTransform...
It works very well with the estimateTransform

```
stitcher.estimateTransform(imgs);
stitcher.composePanorama(pano);
```

But I found another way to compute the imagerotation etc, thats why I want to use composepanorama like this:

```
vector<Mat> imgs;

 imgs.push_back(image1);
 imgs.push_back(image2);
 imgs.push_back(image3);
 imgs.push_back(image4);
 imgs.push_back(image5);
 imgs.push_back(image6);   

stitcher.composePanorama(Inputimages,pano);
```

But everytime I trie this I get this error:

```
Error: Assertion failed (imgs.size() == imgs_.size()) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\stitching\src\stitcher.cpp , line 128
```

Answer (score 3):

If you go into `stitcher.cpp`:

```
Stitcher::Status Stitcher::composePanorama(InputArrayOfArrays images, OutputArray pano)
{
    LOGLN("Warping images (auxiliary)... ");

    std::vector<UMat> imgs;
    images.getUMatVector(imgs);
    if (!imgs.empty())
    {
        CV_Assert(imgs.size() == imgs_.size());
```

So if the global vector `imgs_` is not initialized you'll get that assertion error. Since `imgs_` is initialized in:

```
Stitcher::Status Stitcher::estimateTransform(InputArrayOfArrays images, const std::vector<std::vector<Rect> > &rois)
{
    images.getUMatVector(imgs_);
```

that is why your code is crashing if you don't call `estimateTransform` before `composePanorama`.