# cv2.imread always returns NoneType

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, windows-7

`cv2.imread` is always returning `NoneType`.

I am using python version 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.6 on 64 bit Windows 7.

Maybe it's some kind of bug or permissions issue because the exact same installation of python and cv2 packages in another computer works correctly.  Here's the code:

```
im = cv2.imread("D:\testdata\some.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

I downloaded OpenCV from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv.  Any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: try using cv2.imread(r"D:\testdata\some.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR). The r converts the string to a 'raw string' which does not escape special characters, so you will see a much more reasonable result. This is because by default, python strings accept certain special 'escape sequences'. For example, '\n' is a new line. For more detail, see here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html. Also have a look if the path exists at all.

Comment: import os
print os.path.exists(r'D:\testdata\some.tif'). to see if the path exists. Remove r and I'm sure it wont work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure the path is valid, not containing any single backslashes. Check the other answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954461/463796.

If the path is fixed but the image is still not loading, it might indeed be an [OpenCV bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv) that is not resolved yet, as of 2013. `cv2.imread` is not working properly under Win32 for me either.

In the meantime, use LoadImage, which should work fine.

```
im = cv2.cv.LoadImage("D:/testdata/some.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

Comment: I doubt that it works with this path. You need raw prefix like `r"D:\testdata\some.tif"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre indeed. I changed the answer to point out the path issue and fixed it in the example code. I believe at the time of writing the answer, the workaround was still needed for some images, even with the correct path, so I'm leaving the answer up.

Comment: Image loads but returned type is still None

Comment: @NelsonGon in the context of this question, this seems like an oxymoron. If the image loads, you get a handle, and that can't be None. Do you have any information to add to this answer? Otherwise maybe create a new question with your situation, but provide more info on what exactly happens.

Comment: I could see the image with `imshow` but I could not for instance see the image's `shape` because it was `None` and not an array. In the end, I used `matplotlib`'s `imread` and it seemed to solve the issue(I have no idea why).

Comment: does not work. cv2  does not have a module named cv

Comment: If it can't read it, it should throw an error, not just silently not load the image.

Answer (score 10):

In my case the problem was the spaces in the path. After I moved the images to a path with no spaces it worked.

Answer (score 9):

I also met the same issue before on ubuntu 18.04.

```py
cv2.imread(path)
```

I solved it when I changed the `path` argument from **`Relative_File_Path`** to **`Absolute_File_Path`**.

Hope it be useful.

Comment: idk why this worked but it solved the issue at hand

Comment: i found out that the path was incorrect, the relative path in jupyter is accounted for from the directory where the ipynb file is located but to the contrary if you are running .py file then it depends on where you are running the the command from

Answer (score 8):

Try changing the direction of the slashes

```
im = cv2.imread("D:/testdata/some.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

or add r to the begining of the string

```
im = cv2.imread(r"D:\testdata\some.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

Comment: "*Try changing the direction of the slashes*". Why just *try*? using the escape mark is indeed a mistake, and *must* be corrected, by either solution you mention, or the 3rd one which is to use double \ instead of simple \, the escape sequence built specially for this.

Answer (score 6):

just stumbled upon this one.

The solution is very simple but not intuitive.

- if you use relative paths, you can use either '\' or '/' as in `test\pic.jpg` or `test/pic.jpg` respectively
- if you use absolute paths, you should only use '/' as in `/.../test/pic.jpg` for unix or `C:/.../test/pic.jpg` for windows
- to be on the safe side, just use `for root, _, files in os.walk(<path>):` in combination with `abs_path = os.path.join(root, file)`. Calling imread afterwards, as in `img = ocv.imread(abs_path)` is always going to work.

Comment: On linux, ~/path/file.jpg won't work, have to replace with ~/home/user/path/file.jpg

Comment: Upvoting for suggesting the use of `os.path.join`

Answer (score 6):

In case no one mentioned in this question, another way to workaround is using `plt` to read image, then convert it to `BGR` format.

```py
img=plt.imread(img_path)
print(img.shape)
img=img[...,::-1]
```

it has been mentioned in 
[cv2.imread does not read jpg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files)

Comment: This method works for me. However, the important thing is that `img=img[...,::-1]` rotates the image. To obtain the original image, it should be `img=img[...,::1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This took a long time to resolve. first make sure that the file is in the directory and check that even though windows explorer says the file is "JPEG" it is actually "JPG". The first print statement is key to making sure that the file actually exists. I am a total beginner, so if the code sucks, so be it. 
The code, just imports a picture and displays it . If the code finds the file, then True will be printed in the python window.

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

image_path= "C:/python27/test_image.jpg"
print os.path.exists(image_path)



CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR = 1 # set flag to 1 to give colour image
CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR = 0 # set flag to 0 to give a grayscale one
img = cv2.imread(image_path,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
print img.shape
cv2.namedWindow('Display Window') ## create window for display
cv2.imshow('Display Window', img) ## Show image in the window
cv2.waitKey(0) ## Wait for keystroke
cv2.destroyAllWindows() ## Destroy all windows
```

Answer (score 2):

My OS is Windows 10. I noticed imread is very sensitive to path. No any recommendation about slashes worked for me, so how I managed to solve problem: I have placed file to project folder and typed:
img = cv2.imread("MyImageName.jpg", 0)

So without any path and folder, just file name. And that worked for me.
Also try different files from different sources and of different formats

Comment: I've got Windows 11, and the problem was **letters other than English**.

For example, `cv.imread("../폴더/img.png")` gave me `None`, but `cv.imread("../folder/img.png"` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, changing the name of the image to English alphabetic worked for me. Also, it didn't work with a numeric name (e.g. 1.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,changing direction of slashes worked:

Change `/` to `\`

Comment: "Change / to \ ". You're mistaken. First this is a Python problem, found commonly when writing Windows paths as strings as '\' found in paths is the escape mark in Python. In Python several non printable characters like CR can be escaped, that is written using a combination of the *escape mark* '\' and a letter, e.g '\r' for 'CR'. String '\red' contains an unwanted 'CR'. Second, to prevent this use "a raw string" like 'r\red' where '\' has not particular meaning, use '/' instead of '\' in paths (Python tolerance), or use the escape sequence '\\' made specially to create a simple '\'.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this only to find that this error is caused by a broken image file on my case. So please manually check your file to make sure it is valid and can be opened by common image viewers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped changing file names **to latin** alphabet.

Instead of renaiming all files I wrote a simple wrapper to rename a file before the load into a random guid and right after the load rename it back.

```
import os
import uuid
import cv2

uid = str(uuid.uuid4())


def wrap_file_rename(my_path, function):
    try:
        directory = os.path.dirname(my_path)
        new_full_name = os.path.join(directory, uid)
        os.rename(my_path, new_full_name)
        return function(new_full_name)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)  # use your logger here
    finally:
        os.rename(new_full_name, my_path)


def my_image_read(my_path, param=None):
    return wrap_file_rename(my_path, lambda p: cv2.imread(p) if param is None else cv2.imread(p, param))
```

Comment: to elaborate: paths consisting entirely of ASCII chars will work but any unicode outside of that can cause trouble.

Comment: instead of renaming, you could also use hardlinks (as opposed to symlinks).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, what's the benefit? Will it work faster? On both Win and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the file is corrupted. If it exists and cv2.imread returns None this may be the case.

Try opening the file כfrom file explorer and see if that works

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this. Turns out the PIL module provides this functionality.
Similarly, numpy.imread and scipy.misc.imread both didn't exist until I installed PIL

In my configuration (win7 python2.7), that was done as follows:

```
cd /c/python27/scripts
easy_install PIL
```