# cv2.imread does not read jpg files

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a toolbox in Python where I use `cv2.imread` function to load images.

While I am working with `.png` files it is OK, but it returns `NoneType` when I want to read a `.jpg` file from the same folder.

1. Why does this happen? and how can I fix it?
2. How can I read images from a subfolder?

Thanks

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib1/python2.7/site-packages")
import cv2
im1=cv2.imread('pic1.png')
print im1.shape
#output: (512, 512, 3)
im2=cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
print im2.shape
#output:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2d36ac00eca0> in <module>()
----> 1 print im2.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'


print cv2.getBuildInformation()

Media I/O: 
ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
JPEG:                        /lib64/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
WEBP:                        /lib64/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.6.17)
TIFF:                        /lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
JPEG 2000:                   /lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
```

Two pictures are in my home folder:

[image]

```
  from os import getcwd, listdir, path
  current_dir = getcwd()
  files = [f for f in listdir('.') if path.isfile(f)]
  print(('Current directory: {c_dir}\n\n'
         'Items in the current directory:\n   {files}').format(
         c_dir=current_dir, 
         files=str.join('\n   ', files)))
  #Output:
  Items in the current directory:
  .node_repl_history
  mysh.sh~
  test.sh
  blender_tofile.sh
  **pic1.jpg**
  rapid.sh
  matlab_crash_dump.8294-1
  .gtk-bookmarks
  any2any
  beethoven.ply
  Face.blend
  Untitled1.ipynb
  sphere1.pbrt
  multirow.log
  .Xauthority
  .gtkrc-2.0-kde4
  Theory and Practice.pdf
  simple_example.gpx~
  pbrt.sh
  blender.sh~
  Untitled4.ipynb
  java.log.3414
  kinect_test.py
  matlab_crash_dump.7226-1
 .bashrc~~
 .ICEauthority
 infoslipsviewer.desktop
 GTW_Global_Numbers.pdf
 index.htm
 Untitled2.ipynb
 **pic1.png**



 os.access('pic1.jpg', os.R_OK)
 #output:
 True
```

Comment: Perhaps check output of `print cv2.getBuildInformation()` and see if the library was built with JPEG support.

Comment: please check `os.access('pic1.jpg', os.R_OK)` and tell us the return value

Comment: Is there a possibility that `pic1.png` exists in multiple directories, so that opening the PNG succeeds even though it's looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri that **will not** work.  The `~` shortcut is not understood by `cv2.imread`.  `os.path.expanduser` is required.

Comment: @MarkRansom I renamed both files  into "abcdef", no difference.

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch
Yes, it's in the home directory too.

Comment: Looks like `os.access` checks out.  Could you please try the following, this will tell me if something is off in your build of cv2.  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imread('pic1.jpg')`

Comment: @wim It returns all the pixel values.

Comment: Please refer to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870234/is-there-any-possible-reason-to-have-some-difficulties-with-jpg-files-in-opencv) for the possible solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something is off in your build of `cv2`.  Rebuild it from source, or get it from the package manager.

As a workaround, load jpeg files with matplotlib instead:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a1 = cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
>>> a1.shape
(286, 176, 3)
>>> a2 = plt.imread('pic1.jpg')
>>> a2.shape
(286, 176, 3)
```

Note that opencv and matplotlib read the colour channels differently by default (one is RGB and one is BGR).  So if you rely on the colours at all, you had better swap the first and third channels, like this:

```
>>> a2 = a2[..., ::-1]  # RGB --> BGR
>>> (a2 == a1).all()
True
```

Other than that, `cv2.imread` and `plt.imread` should return the same results for jpeg files.  They both load into 3-channel uint8 numpy arrays.

Comment: @win Let me rebuild cv2. Thanks for your attention :-)

Comment: It could be just a file path problem. When using `cv2.imread(file_path)` make sure the path is correct. I'm running into the same issue and change my file path using full notation.