# Is there any possible reason to have some difficulties with jpg files in opencv while using imread function to read them?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, dependencies, fedora

Recently, I use opencv in python.

As I noticed, when I want to import **cv2** module in python, I need to add **cv2.so** file path manually to the system paths using:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/cv.so')
```

Howewer, when I want to read jpg files in the ipython notebooks, it fails:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib1/python2.7/site-packages")
import cv2
im1=cv2.imread('pic1.png')
print im1.shape
#output: (512, 512, 3)
im2=cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
print im2.shape
#output:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2d36ac00eca0> in <module>()
----> 1 print im2.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Based on [my previous question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files), I rebuilt opencv several times.

I read [somewhere](http://code.opencv.org/issues/69) that it might be the result of some dependency problems. But I have the both packages (libjpeg and libjaspe) on my system:

```
print cv2.getBuildInformation()

Media I/O: 
ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
JPEG:                        /lib64/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
WEBP:                        /lib64/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.6.17)
TIFF:                        /lib64/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
JPEG 2000:                   /lib64/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that `pic1.jpg` is present in your  working directory? The error simply states that the file path is not correct, your all dependencies seem to be fine.

Comment: @ZdaR Yes, I've checked it several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of efforts, I realized that the solution is to add:

```
PYTHONPATH=""
export PYTHONPATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
```

at the end of **/home/.bashrc** file (to make them permanent),
before running **python** or **ipython notebook** from terminal.

**Note**: use only **opencv-python.x86_64** (based on your machine architecture) from yum (dnf) repository (for fedora users of course!) and python **2.7**.

**DO NOT** download opencv from its [website](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). That makes some dependency troubles, I guess.