# cv2 imread returns None

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I installed the cv2 library via pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless.

Whenever i try to read an image it it returns None. I tried using / instead \ in the path, storing the image in the project directory so no / in the path, using r' before the path, re-installing the package. Am i missing something ? woth noting that when i use other libraries to read an image using the same path it works fine.

```
import cv2
 ## I tried all tweaks in the path
img = cv2.imread(path)
print(img)
```

here are the paths i tried

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
print(img)

img = cv2.imread(r'D:\project\image.jpg')
print(img)

img = cv2.imread(r'D:/project/image.jpg')
print(img)

img = cv2.imread('D:/project/image.jpg')
print(img)
```

all the above returned None

Comment: Did you install `pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: First i installed it, after it returned me None i uninstalled it and installed opencv-contrib-python-headless

Comment: Try replacing \ with / in your path to image. Also try copying the image in your program folder.

Comment: Done that already.

Comment: can u comment the path along with filename?does the filename have any space?

Comment: Updated it in post.

Comment: have you tried to read an other image?

Comment: just tried png image and it worked...

Comment: What OS are you using?  If you're using Linux, you'll need to install `libjpeg` as you're using JPEGs images.

Comment: I think that maybe your installation has a problem or your image address is incorrect. There is the same question here with the same problem. It may help you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you to try again installing the CV2 or try to check the image addresses.

If you still have problems you can use other methods for reading the jpeg images.

**As stated in this previous answer [cv2.imread does not read jpg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files)** you can use the matplotlib instead.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img1 = plt.imread('image.jpg')
```

Note that colour channels  are different in matplotlib and it is BGR.

If you need to work with the colors you need to swap third and first channel.

```
img1 = img1[..., ::-1]  # RGB --> BGR
```

you can find more information about matplotlib here https://matplotlib.org/

Hope it solves your problem.