# Unable to use cv.imread()

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm at my wits end just with reading in an image with OpenCV. I'm on a MacBook Mojave 10.14.2. I'm using Spyder 4.0 (Python 3.7)

I have Anaconda navigator 1.9.7 installed. In Anaconda Navigator, I went to Environments > base(root) where I've installed everything I'm using so far, opened the terminal by clicking on the arrow mark and in terminal I've installed OpenCV using:

```
conda install opencv
```

I'm doing the basic tutorial:

```
import cv2
path = r"/Users/anuragnsharma/Desktop/Python/OpenCV_Youtube/data/lena.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(path)
if img is None:
    print("Check file path")
```

and my output is:

```
runcell(0, '/Users/anuragnsharma/.spyder-py3/temp.py')
Check file path
```

As far as I can tell, I've tried trouble shooting in every possible way from as many as 40 different tutorials but I'm unable to carry out this simple reading in of an image even after reinstalling Anaconda and everything in between.

Add to this that there seem to be literally a million different opinions on how to install anaconda and each one seems to solve a specific problem but not tutorial that I've followed so far has helped with this simple issue.

Please help!

Alternatively, can someone provide me with a link to 'rebuild opencv from source'? I have no idea what this means, I've spotted it in a few places so far. If it means that I've got to reinstall, I've done that several times already.

One more clarification, doing the same with Matplotlib works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread("lena.jpg")
img = img[..., ::-1]
print (img)
```

with the output as:

```
runcell(0, '/Users/anuragnsharma/Desktop/Python/OpenCV_Youtube/Tutorial/temp.py')
[[[128 138 225]
  [127 137 224]
  [126 136 223]
  ...
```

Comment: did you try this in python like `python /Users/anuragnsharma/.spyder-py3/temp.py` ? what is the output of `ls /Users/anuragnsharma/Desktop/Python/OpenCV_Youtube/data/lena.jpg` ?

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: @DYZ even if it didn't wouldn't that throw an exception?

Comment: Output for Albin Paul's question: /Users/anuragnsharma/Desktop/Python/OpenCV_Youtube/data/lena.jpg. Also, tried it in python, there is no output.  And yes @DYZ, the file is fine and exists. I'm able to open the file and see the image.

Comment: @SayandipDutta No, it would not.

Comment: @AnuragN.Sharma try putting the image in the same directory and then just put lena.png instead of absolute full path.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265107/cv2-imread-returns-none).

Comment: Can you uninstall your opencv and try with pip install opencv-python

Comment: @Albin Paul, when I try it in the terminal, it works. The same thing after setting the correct working directory in Spyder 4.0, it doesn't. It reverts back to the same error in the main post.

Comment: @ikibir, I've done it about 5 times so far. Apparently, the error comes only while using Spyder.

Comment: @DYZ, mine doesn't read .png images either. I've tried what the duplicate link has suggested but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better create an environment and install opencv and all other necessary packages.I tried your code in jupyter notebook and it works fine.

```
import cv2
path = r"test_images/image1.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(path)
if img is None:
    print("Check file path")
else:
    print("yes")
```

Output:
yes