# OpenCV: AssertionError: Image is not a np.ndarray

Tags: python, opencv

Sometimes, without a specific pattern - meaning it sometimes happens, sometimes not, using the same .jpg pictures as input - the following error is raised:

```
AssertionError: Image is not a np.ndarray
```

As a consequence of normally loading pictures as:

```
imgcv = cv2.imread(image_path)
```

and simply trying to make predictions using a pre-trained model or plotting the image.

**Specifically**, the picture is **not** loaded as *np.arrays*, with three dimensions as (700,700, 3), for instance. Instead, it is stored as **NoneType object of builtins module.**

Which could be the reason of this error?

I am currently using:

```
print(cv2.__version__)
'4.0.0'
```

Comment: Are the images stored locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv2.imread does not read jpg files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files)

Answer (score 1):

Best guess: file system issue.  `cv2.imread(fn)` returns `None` when the file is not found.

I have analysis code that sometimes fails when analyzing videos stored on Synology boxes (i.e., NAS) that tend to go into sleep mode and then wake up too slowly, giving a "file not found" when I first run the analysis; when I re-run it, things work fine.  Similar problems are less likely on local disks or SSDs, but I would not be surprised to see them on VMs, highly loaded machines, or in case a disk is going bad...

Comment: your guest is accurate. should always check the file path when using `cv2.imread()`