# Why is the Python OpenCV code showing the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam

I'm using Python code for using OpenCV in Raspberry PI. My code is shown below.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Project_pi/messi.jpg',0)
    print img[0,0]
```

Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Gayathri.py", line 5, in <module>
    print img[0,0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: @DanMašek oh found this related to jpg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files. I"m going to close as this dupe and delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd check that the file location is correct because if it's not OpenCV doesn't return an Error or Warning, rather makes img `None`. `__getitem__` method of a class is typically used to index an object of that class and obviously you can't index a `None` object.