OpenCV throws Error: (-215:Assertion failed)
Hi I am trying to read in and display a picture with cv2 for further analysis with the following code:
Edit: I added the path with my username being clear to prove it doesn't contain wacky characters. I also tried with multiple .jpg files. I am using opencv-python version 4.9.0.80
import cv2 

path = r'C:\Users\Max\Documents\Pictures\pandas_secondary.jpg'

image = cv2.imread(path) 

window_name = 'image'

cv2.imshow(window_name, image) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

However, this gives me the following error:
error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

The path to my image is correct in my first posted Question I only anonymized it for the question. Now I added the actual path. what am I doing wrong here?
Update: moving the picture to the same directory as my python code leads to the code running for ever, even if the picture is only 20 kb sized. Displaying the picture with pillow works fine though. I also reinstalled cv2 by:
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall opencv-python

which didn't solve the problem.
This is the picture:

os.path.isfile(path)

returns false.

what do you get when you use print(image)

I get None as a result

I think thats part of the problem, yet my path is correct

can you copy the image to the directory where the code is and try cv2.imread("mypic.jpg)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files

I tried to move the picture to the same directory and it now  does give out a lot of numbers

is my directory syntax wrong in some form?

And it runs for over 2 mins now, it shouldnt take that long to read one picture right?

does it plot? How big is the image? @MrIrrelevant

no it doesnt plot, it just runs for minutes now. the image is 22 kb small

can you please post the image? or is that not possible?

if not, try opening it with pillow: image = Image.open("...")

print(image, image.shape)?

opening it with pillow works fine

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847433/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files and i feel it just says reinstall cv2 or use another package.

@MrIrrelevant try that, if it works then flag the question as a duplicate

I tryed, didnt solve the problem

@MrIrrelevant By any chance, is the image a gif? https://forum.opencv.org/t/cv2-imread-does-not-read-jpg-files-the-path-is-right/4380

no its a static image

@MrIrrelevant pre-plexing.

what do you mean by that?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

it's nothing like that but if there are "funny" characters in the path, like if you have a user name that isn't just ascii symbols, then that usually breaks OpenCV's ability to open the file. any "redacting" for the sake of this question hides such details from us.

no i have a normal username its my lastname with no special characters in it

have you tried with a different jpg image ??

assert os.path.isfile(path), in your code, does it throw or not? -- this is not a matter of the code, or opencv. it's something you haven't presented so far. present the file itself. don't paste it into the question, which may change it. put it on a file hoster (dropbox, gdrive, ...), don't need an image hoster changing the file. -- you also haven't made any claims about virtualization of any kind. likely you're running this inside of an environment you aren't even aware of, and this causes the file to not be accessible.

or maybe you installed multiple packages of opencv? pip3 list

please don't grant the bounty to someone who merely repeats all the suggestions from the comments. nor should such behavior be rewarded with upvotes.

@Mr.Irrelevant, please provide the image in your question, so we can see if there is any corruption with the file itself (unlikely since in the comments above you say that it works fine with Pillow). Also, try with a relative path instead, maybe there is something funky with your directories and OpenCV. Finally, try to change all backslashes to forwardslashes (though that should be covered with r''). Did any of this work?

I simply downloaded the pic from: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcStQa0p7RCejEFJ3r4HUVFcI3R4Wh89UwtszB7-RBvPXQ&s

@Mr.Irrelevant did changing the orientation of the slashes solve your problem?

I changed the slashes from \ to / but that didn't solve it. Thx for the suggestion though.

And, @Mr.Irrelevant, have you tried with relative paths to your image?

I would still like feedback on my suggestion to test with os.path.isfile()

os.path.isfile(path) returns false when I try printing it.

ok cool, so now this confirms that this is not an opencv problem but an environment problem.

I am running the code inside a conda environment if that helps.

a mere conda environment shouldn't be able to do this. making files inaccessible could be done by a VM/container (WSL, docker, ...) -- print(os.path.getcwd()) and print(os.listdir(".")), do they show what you expect?

print(os.listdir(".")) lists all other files in the respective directory as expected. print(os.path.getcwd()) throws AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'getcwd'

Can you verify that the script you are running has permission to open the file? Or if your file is accessible to read (i.e., r permission)?

Your code is working for me. I don't see no issue so far.

sorry, my bad, it's just os.getcwd() but if os.listdir() shows all expected files, then... perhaps that file isn't a regular file but perhaps a symbolic link or windows link. please try os.stat(path). if it's a proper file, the result should look like os.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=1125899907064493, st_dev=2224830215, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=6306, st_atime=1713427141, st_mtime=1694594208, st_ctime=1682585062).

@Mr.Irrelevant, can you try to completely delete the line with the path for the file, and re-write it again (do not copy-paste), please? What I am trying to figure out with this is if, maybe, there is an invisible character that has somehow gotten into your file path, but that did not survive the pasting into your question here.

The problem with this error (error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow') is that either the image does not exist, it is corrupted, or the path provided is wrong. Reproducing your problem in my computer, I believe your error lies in the path. Try substituting the forward-slashes for backward-slashes. That solved the problem for me.
If this is not your problem, as some users have pointed out in the comments, try the following code on your computer:
import cv2 

path = r'C:\Users\Max\Documents\Pictures\pandas_secondary.jpg'
window_name = 'image'
image = cv2.imread(path)

if image is None:
    raise Exception("Either the image does not exist, it is corrupted, or the path provided is wrong.")
else:
    cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

If the exception is raised, you have a problem with the library and not with Python. I have tried the above on my computer and it works perfectly (once I changed the orientation of the slashes). If for you, it still does not, maybe try changing the absolute path to the image for a relative one. Finally, what you can do as a last resort is uninstall and reinstall OpenCV, but this is likely not the case. Use the below commands:
python3 -m pip uninstall opencv-python

and
python3 -m pip install opencv-python

EDIT: For some reason, if you are running your code in VS Code while using relative paths, OpenCV does not recognise the file (yielding the error you pointed out) unless you have it in your workspace within the editor.

@anmabe no it's not "taking \ as escape characters". please learn about python's "r-string" feature.

I know what r'' does: avoid taking \ as escape characters!!! I was just pointing out that in my computer using \ for the directory yielded the same error as the OP reported having. Then, I realised that my error arose because directories in my OS are written with / not with , so it could not have been the same problem the OP had. Either way, @ChristophRackwitz, you should remember we are all here trying to help the OP, try to reproduce errors, and make errors ourselves along the way! So, you could spend more time collaborating with others, instead of arguing with them in the comment section.

if image is None:
    print("Error: Image not loaded. Check the file path.")
else:
    window_name = 'image'
    cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

add this and check

what for? this just handles whatever happened with the imread.
