# cv2.imread always returns NoneType python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

`cv2.imread` always returning `NoneType`.

I have the following code:

```
path = cv2.imread('D:/XXX/image.jpg')
```

The array returned is `Nonetype`

But when I use

```
path = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
```

I get the correct array. 
The problem only occurs when I use full path. 
I have tried backslashes and double slash as well, but it makes no difference. There are many similar questions asked before, I have havent got any suitable answer.
The file path and file name are both correct.

I am using Python version 3.6 adn openCV version 3.4.3

**Update**
I tried to get the file path using `tkinter` `filedialog.askopenfilename`. Yet unsuccessful.

Comment: I think you should use double backslashes: `'\\'`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the path is somehow incorrect. Try navigating to it via the command line to check it's validity?

Comment: Use `os.path.join("D:", "XXX", "image.jpg")` (multiple arguments, one per directory) if you want to be cross-platform compatible and/or are not sure about the exact directory separator syntax.

Comment: @rockikz: alredy tried that.

Comment: if the second option works you can check what is your directory with `os.getcwd()` also you can check if the file exists in such path with `os.path.exists(file_path)`

Comment: @BenJones I have checked using `os.path.exists`, it returns `True`

Comment: The image file on in the network drive, is that causing the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv2.imread always returns NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype)

Comment: @TheExorcist I am using python 3.6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using it correctly but missed a parameter.
calling `cv2.imread(jpeg_file,0) yeild a ndtype array object`

however, try this and make sure image file is not zero size.

```
img = cv2.imread(filename_name,0)
```

as the doc says

```
    Use the function cv2.imread() to read an image. The image should be in the working directory or a full path of image should be given.

Second argument is a flag which specifies the way image should be read.

cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag.
cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Loads image in grayscale mode
cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED : Loads image as such including alpha channel
Note Instead of these three flags, you can simply pass integers 1, 0 or -1 respectively.
See the code below:

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
```

[Cv2.imread usage](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

Comment: the second parameter is optional as it can be seen in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56). And one should use the constant (i.e. `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`) rather than 0 when it is needed. The default value of the flag is `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`

Comment: This works when the image is in the working directory, but doest wotk when I use the full path.

Comment: @api55 perfect, didn't go so deep looking.

Comment: Use of magic numbers is an anti-pattern -- this code would not pass even a rudimentary code review. | Changing the second parameter of `imread` from the default `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` would have no effect on the returned data type. It's always a numpy array (except when loading fails, then it returns `None`). The only thing it would change is what (potential) conversions are done after the image has been loaded from file -- in this case it would always return a single channel image, as opposed to always returning a 3 channel image.

Comment: I think the community should delete the answer as the answer doesn't fulfill the purpose of asking.