# Getting an error this line "res = res / 255.0" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, image-processing

I am trying to reshape the image before sending the model to predict which digit it is using Tensorflow(v-2.0), Opencv(v-'3.4.2') with python(v-3.6) but getting the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'".

```
   path=cv2.imread('/home/farhana/Desktop/image processing/code/7.jpg')
     img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
     res=img
     res = res / 255.0
     res = res.resize(28,28)
     res = res.reshape((len(img), 28, 28,1))
     res = res.reshape(28,28,1)
```

Comment: Error checking is crucial. Just about all file-operations can fail, and for some reason tend to always fail when you don't check for errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Nonetype to int or string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930188/how-to-convert-nonetype-to-int-or-string)

Comment: I checked the image is in that exact directory but don't understand the problem actually.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: interestingly, `cv2.imread(None, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` just returns `None`, without raising an error.

Comment: Think a bit more about `path=cv2.imread("0.jpg")` and how you then use `path`... Is `path` really a path to an image file?

Comment: Again, think about what the variable `path` really is. And I doubt the path (an *actual* path) you pass to the first call to `imread` is valid, isn't it missing a slash `/` somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv2.imread always returns NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these three lines:

```
path=cv2.imread('/home/farhana/Desktop/image processing/code/7.jpg')
img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
res=img
```

In the first line you read an image file, and store the image object in the (badly named) variable `path`.

In the second line you pass the image object from the first call to `imread` as a path to another call to `imread`. Since the image object isn't actually a path then the second call will fail and return `None`.

Then the last line makes `res` reference the `None` object returned by the second call `imread`, and since it's `None` it can't be used for any operations.

It seems that the second call to `imread` shouldn't happen.