# GOOGLE COLAB: cv2.imread return NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, google-colaboratory

I could not use `cv2.imread` in google colab. I tried like this;

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')
print(type(img))

>> `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

I dont know why it is giving this out put!! I tried below this again... using `r`

```
img = cv2.imread(r'/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')
```

I could not figure out why it is returning a `NoneType` object. There is no issue with the picture path. 
I tried the following link, but could not succeed. 
[cv2.imread always returns NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype)

Comment: change it to `img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')`

Comment: Perhaps the space in the path between My Drive is causing a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope my solution will help someone. 
In my case, calling `img = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')` was actually a part of a function in FASTER RCNN. I could not resolve any other existing methods in the internet. Finally I did it like below and it worked.

First of all I think the problem is `cv2.imread()` doesnt recognize `My Drive`.. the space between `My` & `Drive`. Although I recognized this from the beginning, my attempt was like below..

```
"/content/gdrive/'My Drive'/path_to_image/1.png"
```

But simply putting `My Drive` in a `single quotation` didnt work!!

It must be like below to work in my case;

```
"/content/gdrive/"+"My Drive"+"/path_to_image/1.png"
```

Edited:

I came up with another solution to overcome this annoying `"My Drive"` issue in Colab.

**step 1:**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive/")
```

**step 2:**

```
import os
os.getcwd()
!mkdir MyDrive   # make a directory called MyDrive
```

**step 3:**

```
!mount --bind /content/drive/My\ Drive /content/MyDrive
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you sharing the solution. I came up with a simpler one to import the image from google driver.

step 1:

```
#import google driver
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive/")
```

step2:

```
img0 = cv2.imread('/content/MyDrive/image_path/image.jpg')
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use load_img from keras.preprocessing.image to load images in google colab.

```
img = load_img('/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')
```

it returns ing. you may need to use img_to_array from keras.preprocessing.image if you want to get it to an array.

```
arr = img_to_array(img)
```

these are all image processing I usually import:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array,array_to_img,save_img
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your image path. Either like @sK500 suggested instead of gdrive it must be drive. Check your mount statement.

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Also if you have directly mounted drive using UI then it will be drive instead of gdrive. If this is not wrong then you instead use the UI on the left side to surf files and reach your target image. Then right click on it and copy its path.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is simple typo in

replace the following line from

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png').
```

to

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/path_to_image/1.png')
```

I tried exactly same (removing `g` from `gdrive`). For some reason, colab doesn't throw an error when the folder is wrong.

```
img = cv2.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/cat.png')
print(type(img))

#output
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```