# Failing to load a picture through cv2 (opencv 4.4) while opening it with PIL works

Tags: python, opencv

I have a bunch of pictures that I can load perfectly well using various methods, for instance Image.open. But when it comes to opencv, I get nothing:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import cv2

 for fi in os.listdir():
            image = cv2.imread(fi)
            print(image)

            image = Image.open(fi)
            print(image)
            print(np.array(image.getdata()))
```

returns:

```
None
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=1920x1080 at 0x8AF2A30>
[[31 63 84]
 [31 63 84]
 [31 63 84]
 ...
 [16 16 16]
 [16 16 16]
 [16 16 16]]
```

It remains the same whatever value I give for the second argument of imread. Giving an explicit path does not bring any change either.

My files are 1920*1080 RGB png files, I'm using python 3.7.3 and opencv 4.4.0.44.

Thanks for your help

EDIT 1 :

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.4.0

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-09-23T00:00:53Z
    Host:                        Windows 6.3.9600 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.18.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2
      requested:                 SSE2
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24241.7)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise  /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise  /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise  /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG 
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise  /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          ade wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-4q0kz99f/_skbuild/win32-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-4q0kz99f/_skbuild/win32-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-4q0kz99f/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python37/python.exe (ver 3.7.5)
    Libraries:                   C:/Python37/libs/python37.lib (ver 3.7.5)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-build-env-5cllkua4/overlay/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.5)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-4q0kz99f/_skbuild/win32-3.7/cmake-install
```

EDIT 2

```
File: ... (1273217 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    1920 x 1080 image, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk pHYs at offset 0x00025, length 9: 11811x11811 pixels/meter (300 dpi)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x0003a, length 65536
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, default compression
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x10046, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x20052, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x3005e, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x4006a, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x50076, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x60082, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x7008e, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x8009a, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x900a6, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xa00b2, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xb00be, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xc00ca, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xd00d6, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xe00e2, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0xf00ee, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x1000fa, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x110106, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x120112, length 65536
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x13011e, length 27727
  chunk IEND at offset 0x136d79, length 0
No errors detected in ... (23 chunks, 79.5% compression).
```

EDIT 3

```
Image:
  Filename: ...png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Resolution: 118.11x118.11
  Print size: 16.256x9.14402
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 2073600
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 88.4175 (0.346735)
      standard deviation: 48.6837 (0.190916)
      kurtosis: 2.88645
      skewness: 1.60217
      entropy: 0.667925
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 78.7912 (0.308985)
      standard deviation: 52.3865 (0.205437)
      kurtosis: 2.33529
      skewness: 1.54681
      entropy: 0.672343
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 134.848 (0.528816)
      standard deviation: 81.9142 (0.321232)
      kurtosis: -1.36843
      skewness: -0.507794
      entropy: 0.668643
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 100.686 (0.394846)
      standard deviation: 60.9948 (0.239195)
      kurtosis: -0.758096
      skewness: 0.627416
      entropy: 0.669637
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Convex hull: 0,0 1919,0 1919,1039 1915,1079 104,1079 17,1066 16,1065 0,1039 0,0
  Minimum bounding box: 1919,0 1919,1079 0,1079 0,0
  Properties:
    date:create: 2020-10-21T19:06:24+00:00
    date:modify: 2020-10-21T19:22:08+00:00
    minimum-bounding-box:_p: 0,0
    minimum-bounding-box:_q: 1919,0
    minimum-bounding-box:_v: 1915,1079
    minimum-bounding-box:angle: 0
    minimum-bounding-box:area: 2.0706e+06
    minimum-bounding-box:height: 1919
    minimum-bounding-box:unrotate: -0
    minimum-bounding-box:width: 1079
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
    png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 1920, 1080
    png:pHYs: x_res=11811, y_res=11811, units=1
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    signature: bcf111b6c823a95bd31bbec26225847dffa81c1a07cbf95cf07396f5404ffa5c
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 1.21423MiB
  Number pixels: 2073600
  Pixels per second: 28.8118MP
  User time: 0.063u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.071
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-34 Q16 x64 2020-10-08 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: Agree with @MarcSances. The problem is, ``os.listdir()``only gives the filenames, but cv2 needs the absolute path to the image (or at least it is highly recommended to always use absolute paths due to issues like this).

Comment: Thanks @MarcSances. I have made the change but it still returns None.

Comment: (venv) ... >pip install opencv-python

Collecting opencv-python

  Downloading opencv_python-4.4.0.44-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (24.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.5 MB 6.8 MB/s

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in ...\venv\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.2)

Installing collected packages: opencv-python

Successfully installed opencv-python-4.4.0.44

Comment: Yes, the extensions are correct :(

Comment: Maybe you could share an *"unhappy"* PNG file via Dropbox or Google Drive or similar.

Comment: Maybe you could also share the output from `cv2.getBuildInformation()
`

Comment: might even be an actual bug... uhh searching I've found this question here in SO which is very related if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype

Comment: It's possible there's an issue with your PNG file that PIL is more forgiving about than OpenCV is prepared to accept. I'd recommend running your PNG through `pngcheck` with all verbose options on. Also through **ImageMagick** with `magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE.PNG` and checking the output for issues.

Comment: @MarcSances Thanks for the link. Theur solution is outdated but that gave me an idea on how to get on with it for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not solve the imread issue, but I have found a way around that makes it for my purpose:

```
    image = Image.open(fi)
    im_arr = np.array(image.getdata(), dtype=np.uint16).reshape(1080, 1920, 3)
    im_arr = np.vectorize(lambda x: x/255)(im_arr)
    cv2.imshow("image", im_arr)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

I'm gonna investigate further the issue though.

EDIT :

Also this seems to work and is more satisfying, despite the time and space consumed by the read and write process:

```
    image = Image.open(fi)
    im_arr = np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(1080, 1920, 3)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_data, "image_data_clean", rep, fi), im_arr)
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_data, "image_data_clean", rep, fi))
```

And in that case, I indeed need no type declaration and no mapping (but still reshaping)

EDIT 2 :

Wanting to explore the possibility the files could have been corrupted, I unzipped them anew from the source. I carelessly put them at the same place, so I lost the previous ones and thus the possibility to compare. However, when I run on the new files:

```
    test = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_data, "image_data", rep, fi))
    print(test)
    im_arr = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(path_data, "image_data", rep, fi)))
    print(im_arr.shape)
    print(im_arr.dtype)
    cv2.imshow("image", im_arr)
    cv2.waitKey()
>>>
None
(1080, 1920, 3)
uint8
```

Then I now get the expected answers for shape and dtype and imshow works perfectly without reshaping/type declaration! I'm really sure it wasn't the case this morning so it must be the files at fault - or my brain - and not PIL

However, direct attempts with imread still fail sadly

Comment: It should be enough to do `im_arr = np.array(Image.open(fi))`

Comment: If I don't add a type argument I get a:
```  error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'
```

If I don't reshape I get a (2073600, 3) array which technically does not throw exceptions but does not lead to the expected result either.

On the other hand, you're right that the x/255 mapping is actually not necessary when it comes to showing the image. I just need it for further cv processing, like cv2.threshold()

Thanks a lot for the help guys!

Comment: There's something wrong here. Please run the code in my comment two lines above here and then print `im_arr.shape` and `im_arr.dtype` PIL **knows** the shape and type of the image so you *should not have to* tell it to Numpy or OpenCV.

Comment: Something weird happened I'm gonna edit in the post for more clarity.