# Getting a 'NoneType' Object Not Subscriptable on a Python script for Digit Recognition

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

So I decided to try out a digit recognition system, and it works when reading from thr `MNIST` database but when I try to import my own images I get an error saying `'NoneType' Object Is Not Subscriptable` on the second line of the following code snippet. I have imported `cv2` as `cv` and all the correct imports are there and have been given appropriate aliases.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#the neural network setup code

for x in range(1, 6):
    img = cv.imread(f'{x}.png')[:, :, 0]  # where x is the name of the file e.g '5.png'
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f' The result is probably: {np.argmax(prediction)}')
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) opencv's imread returns None if the image cannot be opened. So in your code there's a change of you doing:

```
None[:, :, 0]
```

Hence the error, because you're subscribing to None. So you may want to try some None-safety like this:

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    img = cv.imread(f'{x}.png')
    if img:
        img = img[:, :, 0]
        img = np.invert(img) # should already be a numpy array
    else:
        print("could not open image")
```

If opencv is somehow always returning None, you might want to check this question: [cv2.imread always returns NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype)

Comment: The cause of the error was correct but your solution didn't work unfortunately. However, due to the resources you linked, I came across the cause. I needed to indicate a raw file path to the pictures and also uninstall and reinstall Qt and PyQt. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The file can't be opened, producing a `None` result.
Instead use a raw file path.
After this you may encounter an error concerning Qt, in which case uninstall and reinstall Qt and PyQt.

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    img = cv.imread(fr'[file path]\{x}.png')[:, :, 0]  # where x is the name of the file e.g '5.png'
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f' The result is probably: {np.argmax(prediction)}')
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```