# Opencv 4.5 1 :Unable to read image through Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror

I am making a python program for Optical Character Recognition for which I need to read the image file from the directory. Image file lies in the same directory as my python script . I am unable to read the file through `cv2.imread()` and it is returning a `Nonetype` object. However when I am running the same script through **cmd** i am not getting any error. Why is it happening? The directory where image and script lie is included in my system path variable as I confirmed through `sys.path` variable.

**P.S. :** I have appended the `sys.path` variable to include a **package directory** where other  **utility modules** lie which i have to use in my script. I am using **ATOM**.

Here is the code.

```
#recognizedigits.py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/HP ELITEBOOK 820G3/Documents/GitHub/Computer_vision/Mini_Projects/Helper_classes")

from transform import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import imutils
import cv2


image = cv2.imread(r"example.jpeg")
image = imutils.resize(image ,height = 500)
```

Here is my directory structure.

[image: Directory Structure]

Error which I am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP ELITEBOOK 820G3\Documents\GitHub\Computer_vision\Mini_Projects\OCR_Reader\recognizedigits.py", line 13, in <module>
    image = imutils.resize(image ,height = 500)
  File "C:\Users\HP ELITEBOOK 820G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
[Finished in 0.621s]
```

Comment: refer to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949268/cv2-imread-always-returns-nonetype/26954461#26954461