# TypeError: Image data of dtype <U52 cannot be converted to float

Tags: python

I don't understand. My code works in google collab when I put the images in my drive, but when I try it on Vs code, it doesn't work....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = 'P:\Comptabilité\Dynamat\Tri'


CATEGORIES = ['Oui','Non']

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
        break
    break

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2684, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1599, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5679, 
in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\slatreille\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 685, in set_data
    "float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
>>>
```

Here is the error I get. I tried to reach the path outside of the for loop, and it works, that's where I'm getting confuse...

Comment: What is the full error message and which version of python are you running on each machine?

Comment: I am using Python 3.9 for VS code. For google collab, I don't know actually...
The full error message is edited in the questions !

Comment: Could you print 1) the array, 2) the type of the array, please

Comment: It prints out as None.... but I can clearly see that img is an images when I put my cursor over it.

Comment: That's the issue then,  cv2 is not able to read your file. I think this answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949572/12992939

Comment: I read this thread allready, still not working. The path does exist (os.path.exists returns true) I tried with plt.imread and still the same problem. the thing that concerns me is that the code works when I do it on IDLE... I just liked VS code since its more ''user friendly''

Comment: If it works in IDLE I suggest checking that each python version is the same