# OPENCV linking Error - Win32 & VS2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

i have build openCV 3.0.0 both alpha & beta versions. but everytime i run my project i get this Error only for "imread" function:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class cv::String const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _main    ...
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat a=Mat::zeros(10,10,0);
    Mat b;
    b=imread("Mu.jpg");
    imshow("s",a);
    waitKey(1000);

}
```

when i remove the "imread" function it works fine. builds and runs with no errors and displays the little black image (from "A" Matrix)
I have Re-Build the solutions & OpenCV from scratch and still getting this error.

I'm working with VS2012 and i have added the include & lib paths in a property sheet for the project.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: imread was moved from highgui to imgcodecs in 3.0, so , different header / lib

Comment: Thank you very much!! it's fixed!!!
it's wired thogh, because `imread` signature is also in highgui header, so only the lib file needed change, i guess it could be counted as bug...

Comment: " because imread signature is also in highgui header" - i guess, that's more to faciliate the transition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imread` function has been moved to `imgcodecs` library so you have to include it :

***For MSVC users :*** add "opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib" to "configuration properties-> Linker->Input->Aditional Dependencies" and include "#include "

***For Qt users :*** For Qt IDE users add `-lopencv_imgcodecs300d` or `-lopencv_imgcodecs300` to your .pro file
and `#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>` to your main file

*note:* *the number 300 in the lib name should be changed to match OpenCV* version used.

Answer (score 0):

This unresolved external symbol linker errors basically arrives when the compiler is not able to get the definition of that function which is declared.

So make sure you have defined `imread("Mu.jpg"){}` somewhere in your code and then try compiling the same.

Check whether you have linked the libraries properly and also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv) may be useful if you are using opencv2.2.

Comment: [`imread()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) is *supposed* to be part of the opencv2 library, assuming it is being linked properly the error posted should't happen. It isn't something the user is supposed to have to *define*.

Comment: How can i be sure that it's being linked properly? isn't "imshow" being linked and executed enough?