# Highgui.imread returns a Mat with size 0x0

Tags: android, image, opencv

I'm using OpenCV on Android with Eclipse for the first time.
I used the following line to read an image and the next one to get its size:

Mat m = Highgui.imread("C:/Users/IMG_5940.jpg");
Size size = m.size();

and Size returns 0x0.
I therefore can't convert the image to a bitmap and I receive the error: width and height must be > 0.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the image path is spelled correctly? Do you have a second image for which the read works? Are you on a Windows machine? If, have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

Usually when `imread` returns an image of zero by zero pixels, the image could not be read. You have two options:

First, you can have IMG_5940.jpg as a Resource in your Android project, and import it with the OpenCV `Utils.loadResource` function with something like:

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(context, referenceID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Second, if you know the location of the image on your *Android* filesystem, e.g, you're getting it from a camera or you've asked the user to provide a valid image, then you can use the `imread` function with that [File object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) like so:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());
```