# C++ OpenCV imread file path format for windows

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I've tried to google this to no avail. Please help me understand what is wrong with this file path:

```
Mat lena = imread("C:\Users\dasboomer\Desktop\Building-Computer-Vision-Projects-with-OpenCV4-and-CPlusPlus-master\Chapter03/lena.jpg");
```

I've tried changing:

- backslash to double backslash
- backslash to forward slash
- backslash to double forward slash

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imread not working in Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is used for an escape sequence.

Instead, use the below lines of code:

```
Mat lena = imread("C:\\Users\\dasboomer\\Desktop\\Building-Computer-Vision-Projects-with-OpenCV4-and-CPlusPlus-master\\Chapter03\\lena.jpg");
```

or

```
Mat lena = imread("C:/Users/dasboomer/Desktop/Building-Computer-Vision-Projects-with-OpenCV4-and-CPlusPlus-master/Chapter03/lena.jpg");
```

Comment: You are correct, it turns out the tutorial code was faulty. My my, where has packt gone?

Comment: Hi Rahul! Yes. For some reason, the code that follows was flagging it as not loaded.   // Create windows
 namedWindow("Lena", WINDOW_NORMAL);
 // Checking if Lena image has been loaded
  if (!lena.data) {
   cout << "Lena image missing!" << endl;
   return -1;
  }