# qt opencv can't read the image

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm quite new around the qt creator and I'm sick of it's building errors and tones of undefined errors. Eventually i installed opencv3.2 with no error. Noti can use opencv libraries but i can't read the files like "image.jpg". I tried everything. Path is %100 correct slashes are correct. There were no error during the cmake installation. Pls give me hand :D

```
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_core320.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_highgui320.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs320.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_imgproc320.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_features2d320.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv3.2\build\bin\libopencv_calib3d320.dll
```

```
try {
     Mat image = imread("D:\\Adsız.jpeg",0);
     if (!image.data)
         cout << "Data is empty" << endl;
    
     namedWindow("My image");
     imshow("My image",image);
     waitKey();
} catch (const exception& e) {

}
```

Output

```
10:50:24: Starting C:\Users\YUNUS EMRE\Qt Workspace\build-OpenCVTest-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release\release\OpenCVTest.exe ...
Data is empty
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file C:\opencv3.2\sources\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 312
[]10:50:27: C:\Users\YUNUS EMRE\Qt Workspace\build-OpenCVTest-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_32_bit-Release\release\OpenCVTest.exe exited with code 0
```

It returns empty image.

Comment: Something here might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv

Comment: Are you sure that the image actually exists at the path you specified? Also I don't think you can leave the flags `0`. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: yes %100 sure the path is correct. I tried waitkey(0), waitkey(5000) and nothing is  changed

Comment: Did you add `INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\include` too like LIBS ?

Comment: And also try this path `D://Adsız.jpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing Opencv 4.4.0 . It was a little bit hard to install but i figured it out thanks for replies.