# OpenCV not working correctly in Qt debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am working with OpenCV 2.4.9 under Windows 8.1 x64. I am trying to run basic operations like image reading, webcam streaming, etc. I've configured OpenCV to work with VS and QtCreator.

In both cases I use precompiled binaries from the `x64/vc12` OpenCV folder, built with the VC compiler version 12.0. In Visual Studio everything works great in both release and debug modes, but in Qt Creator only release mode works correctly while in debug mode I encounter strange bugs like: wrong windows titles, `imread` not working correctly, bad video streaming.

In Qt Creator I use the same compiler as in VS, namely vc12. I've setup the library paths correctly and am using debug version of libs for debug and appropriate ones for release.
The problems only arise when I am using C++ API in OpenCV, everything works fine if I am using the C API.

I've seen problems like mine arise regularly [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584273/issue-with-reading-an-image-using-cvimread-function-in-opencv), but none of those solutions solve my problem.

**UPDATE**: *Problem solved*, see the answer below.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), otherwise it feels a bit self-reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

It was in the Qt Creator's *qmake*, it did not correctly update the Makefile that it generates. So, instead of debug versions of the libraries, the release versions were used, but the *.pro* file in the project showed just the opposite.